# React Native Did not get valid calls back from JS Error

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

often when I have the Chrome Dev Tools open while developing React Native Android on my device, I get the following Error:

```
Did not get valid calls back from JS: [[],[],[],[],[]]

callFunction
ReactBridge.java:-2

run
CatalystInstanceImpl.java:203

...
```

Any idea whats wrong?
I'm using react-native v0.19 with a Nexus 5

Comment: Here are all of the cases that can produce that error: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/jni/react/MethodCall.cpp#L23-L50

Comment: The project structure has changed somewhat, so the relevant file is now at: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactCommon/cxxreact/MethodCall.cpp (however, it's probably a good idea to just search for that error string in the repo, in case the files move again).

Answer (score 0):

This error should no longer be appearing as of React Native 0.23 when debugging with Chrome Dev Tools. The issue was the debugger returning "bogus values" to the app when it fails to handle a request. See [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/2c6a81d4451e0c873ef2a39019122ca4879a4f77) commit for the fix.

However, this error still sometimes occurs when debugging with Nuclide. [Here](https://github.com/facebook/nuclide/issues/709) is the issue I opened regarding that problem.

Either way, the app showing this error is just a symptom, where the real problem is that a request from the app to the debugger (in its role as the JS engine) couldn't be handled.

One specific reason I ran into was the Batched Bridge not being set, due to the debugger failing to load the JS app bundle (in my case this was caused by issues with the port at which it tried to fetch the bundle). However, there are probably many other reasons this might happen.